# Java modified coin flip

Tags: java

Hi I need a little help I keep receiving 2 minor errors

```
C:\Users\ez\Documents\HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin.java:16: error: illegal start of expression
                    public Coin();
                    ^
C:\Users\ez\Documents\HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin.java:38: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
                    public Coin(String s)
                           ^
2 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

---

My actual code is:

```
public class ModifiedCoin {
  private String sideUp;
  {
    Random rc = new Random();
    public Coin();
    {
      int rg = rc.nextInt(2);
      if(rg == 0)
        sideUp = "Heads";
      else sideUp = "Tails";
    }
  }
  public void toss() {
    int rg = rc.nextInt(2);
    if(rg == 0)
      sideUp = "Heads";
    else
      sideUp = "Tails";
  }
  public String getSideUp() {
    return sideUp;
  }
  public Coin(String s) {
    sideUp = s;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the entire contents of the file? it looks like you are missing the outer class declaration

Comment: looks like you might be missing a package declaration.. is this class defined in a package?

Comment: Also in Java the file has to have the same name as the class defined inside of it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. By the looks of the error, you are trying to define a method inside another method. That is not possible in Java. Given you originally also taged `intro.js`, are you sure you should be using Java, and not for example JavaScript?

Comment: `invalid method declaration; return type required` means that it doesn't recognize that `Coin` is supposed to be a constructor. This needs to be inside a class declaration named `Coin`.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is you're using constructors in a file that isn't named Coin.java.  You would probably want to rename HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin.java to Coin.java, and likely rename the class from public class HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin to public class Coin.

In most cases, your filename, public class * and your constructor are all the same name.

Also, I agree with the other answer saying remove the first semicolon.  Here is an example of these changes (in a file named `HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin .java`):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin {
  private String sideUp;
  private Random rc = new Random();

  public HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin()
  {
    int rg = rc.nextInt(2);
    if(rg == 0)
      sideUp = "Heads";
    else
    sideUp = "Tails";
  }
  public HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin(String s) {
    sideUp = s;
  }

  public void toss() {
    int rg = rc.nextInt(2);
    if(rg == 0)
      sideUp = "Heads";
    else
      sideUp = "Tails";
  }
  public String getSideUp() {
    return sideUp;
  }

  public static void main(String ... args) {
    HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin c = new HoustonJacoriemodifiedCoin();
    c.toss();
    System.out.println(c.getSideUp());
    c.toss();
    System.out.println(c.getSideUp());
    c.toss();
    System.out.println(c.getSideUp());
    c.toss();
    System.out.println(c.getSideUp());
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you posted the full code after I posted my answer, so my answer isn't as correct as it should be.  Your original code, where the class name was `ModifiedCoin` was correct. You file name needs to be `ModifiedCoin.java`.  Your Constructors need to be `ModifiedCoin` also.

Answer (score 0):

This is the corrected code:

`public class ModifiedCoin {
  private String sideUp;
     Random rc = new Random();
    public ModifiedCoin ()
    {
      int rg = rc.nextInt(2);
      if(rg == 0)
        sideUp = "Heads";
      else sideUp = "Tails";
    }
  public void toss() {
    int rg = rc.nextInt(2);
    if(rg == 0)
      sideUp = "Heads";
    else
      sideUp = "Tails";
  }
  public String getSideUp() {
    return sideUp;
  }
  public ModifiedCoin (String s) {
    sideUp = s;
  }
}`